# Change the size of modal in ngDialog

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

does ngDialog allow different sizes of modal?

For example, bootstrap-angular modal has such function:

```
$modal.open('sm') or $modal.open('lg')
```

which will open small and large modals respectively.

Is there such thing in ngDialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the option to set a custom class, e.g. your bootstrap class or so:

```
ngDialog.open({
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
});
```

you'll find further documentation in the official api [documentation](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#api).

Comment: I had the same idea, but the documentation does not show how to create a custom class. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @JohnyStark I think, you can add whatever css class you want (you have to create a new design class in your css file) and then add this classname as option in the call.